# Is there a way to integrate the S3's ACL with my own user repository?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, spring-security, storage

I am writing a java ee application, with its own users and roles repository (based on the Spring Security Framework). In the application, some users upload large files.

I want these files to be protected (i.e. only the person who uploaded the file should have the right to access it; in fact the authorization logic is a bit more complex than that). My users don't have any aws account.

I would like to store these files on S3, but I haven't found a way to do it securely. Indeed, I haven't found a way to express an ACL that would reference my users and roles.

I have thought about generating opaque names for my files (that would be hard to guess). My java ee application could ensure that access to the web page that contains a link to the file is protected. Some level of protection, but it seems pretty fragile against a brute force attachk.

Any idea?